# Strip trailing zeros from float while aligning with format()

Tags: python, string-formatting

I'm trying to store a float to file that can sometimes contain trailing zeros.

When appliyng `{:g}` the result is the expected: the trailing zeros are removed. The issue comes when I try to align the float in the text file, in this case I use `{:>10.0g}` and the result is the float written in scientific notation instead of just having its trailing zeros stripped.

Here's a MWE:

```
a = 546.0
b = 6785.35416

with open('format_test.dat', 'a') as f_out:
    f_out.write('{:g} {:>15.3f}'.format(a, b)) # <-- NO ZEROS BUT NOT ALIGNED
    f_out.write('\n')
    f_out.write('{:>10.0g} {:>15.3f}'.format(a, b)) # <-- ALIGNED BUT IN SC NOTATION
```

the output:

```
546        6785.354
     5e+02        6785.354
```

Is there any way to fix this from the `format()` end without having to tamper with the float before passing it on?

Comment: I was so determined I should use `{:g}` to remove trailing zeros that I didn't even think of using `0.f`. Would you mind posting your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`g` will automatically switch to scientific notation, depending on the magnitude of the value (see [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings)). You can get what you want by using `f` for both values:

```
>>> '{:>10.0f} {:>15.3f}'.format(546.0, 6785.354)
'       546        6785.354'
```